# Statically configure rel in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm profiling a [simple Spring Boot 1.5 Spring Data REST application](https://github.com/JanStureNielsen/so-music). To my surprise, the [Atteo Evo Inflector](https://github.com/atteo/evo-inflector) is a tremendous hot-spot at over half the CPU according to [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html):

[image]

You should be able to reproduce this with [Apache Bench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html):

```
ab2 -c 1 -n 10000 http://localhost:8080/people
```

The repository is:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository 
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

and the ([Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html)-ed) data:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyLocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = LocalDate.parse(birthDate);
    }
}
```

Why is Spring HATEOAS trying to inflect the `@RepositoryRestResource` repository when the repository defines the `collectionResourceRel` statically? Any ideas what the correct annotations are to configure my Spring Data REST application to avoid the runtime inflection overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@RestResource(rel="people", path="people")` to your entity:
`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@RestResource(rel="people", path="people")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyLocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = LocalDate.parse(birthDate);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, if Spring HATEOUS does not find a `@RestResource` annotation on the entity, [it delegates to the Atteo Evo Inflection rel provider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/mapping/TypeBasedCollectionResourceMapping.java#L96), even if the entity's repository is a `@RepositoryRestResource`. Since both the entity and the repository now have `rel` and `path` (duplicate) information you need to be careful to keep these in sync. I've opened [a Spring Data REST issue on this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1073).